# How can I get marked to render tables without adding CSS?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, javascript-marked

I am using [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) which supports github flavored markdown. This includes [table support](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables):

```
var marked = require('marked');

var markdown = `
| API        | Documented CSP Policy           |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
|Google Fonts|No documented policy|
|Mixpanel|No documented policy|
|Ractive.js|[Documented policy](http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/csp)|
|Stripe|[Documented policy](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-about-pci-dss-3-1)|

`

console.log(marked(markdown));
```

However the output has a bunch of unnecessary inline styles:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>API</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Documented CSP Policy</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Google Fonts</td>
<td style="text-align:center">No documented policy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mixpanel</td>
<td style="text-align:center">No documented policy</td>
</tr>
(etc etc)
```

**How can I get marked to just render the HTML without adding CSS?**

Answer (score 1):

OK found the answer: intercept `renderer.tablecell` and set `flags.align` to `null`

```
var marked = require('marked');
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
var realTableCellRenderer = renderer.tablecell
renderer.tablecell = function(content, flags){
    flags.align = null;
    return realTableCellRenderer(content, flags)
}

var markdown = `
| API        | Documented CSP Policy           |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
|Google Fonts|No documented policy|
|Mixpanel|No documented policy|
|Ractive.js|[Documented policy](http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/csp)|
|Stripe|[Documented policy](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-about-pci-dss-3-1)|
|Twitter oembed API|No documented policy, but [some CSP notes](https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/widgets-webpage-properties#csp)|
|Typekit|[Documented policy](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/1265956-content-security-policy-and-typekit)|
|Stormpath|No documented policy|

`

console.log(marked(markdown, { renderer: renderer }));
```

Returns clean output:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>API</th>
<th>Documented CSP Policy</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Google Fonts</td>
<td>No documented policy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mixpanel</td>
<td>No documented policy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ractive.js</td>
<td><a href="http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/csp">Documented policy</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```